# Implementing a word list for use in an android application

Tags: android, xml, arrays

I am developing an android application and would like to be able to create an array consisting of words from an xml file, but am unsure of how that would look. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: What is the format (or schema) for your xml file?  The overall strategy would be to parse the xml file (perhaps using buildin JSON) and put appropriate field values into  a list.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this if you just need a preset list

In your `res/values` folder there should be an `arrays.xml` file if there isnt create it.

Then withiin the file add something like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
<array name="myarray">
    <item>first item</item>
    <item>second item</item>
    <item>third item</item>
    <item>foruth item</item>
</array>
</resources>
```

then do access it do this

```
String[] text = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.myarray);
```